# HttpPost and HttpGet object to url so as to be able to use with Volley?

Tags: java, android, apache, android-volley

Volley gives us better efficiency, however it uses the "url"

```
JsonObjectRequest j = new JsonObjectRequest((int method, String url, JSONObject jsonRequest, Listener<JSONObject> listener, ErrorListener errorListener);
```

But if I have to use HttpPost or HttpGet object as I have to set Header and Entity etc. How can I do it while still using Volley.

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
httpGet.setHeader("String", "something" );
httpGet.setHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
...
httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity("whatever"));
```

basically after these lines of code I get HttpPost / HttpGet object; is there a way to use this object in volley instead of using HttpClient to execute the request.

Or is there a some different way to set header etc and then use it with Volley.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think it may help you get the idea:

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
                                Request.Method.POST,
                                url,
                                jsonRequest,
                                new JSONResponseListener(this),
                                new JSONResponseErrorListener(this)){
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            return headers;
        }

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams()  {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("username", username);
            params.put("password", password);

            return params;
        }
    };
    MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
```

Answer (score 1):

Override the getHeaders() method in the Volley request object. Then return a map containing the headers from that method.

Comment: Thanks, well do you know where can I find documentation about Volley, the one given on developers.android.com does not seems sufficient.

Comment: like I want to know how can I do a synchronous request with volley, so that after if  I add request A,B,C in queue they will be executed in same order A,B,C

Comment: As far as I can tell, you'd be better off using something else in this scenario. Volley is explicitly async and multi-threaded, so in your case, A, B, and C would be expected to run in parallel with Volley.